# Sphinx Search: Partial keyword

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search, sphinx, keyword-search

I've started using **Sphinx** and I tried to install the sphinx. Everything is working properly but i want to search for partial keyword. And I want to know how to display the results in webpage.
Ex.
I search '**ate**'
The result should be : '**ate**', '**update**', '**late**', '**hate**', etc.
My sphinx.con :

```
source src1
{
  type          = mysql
  sql_host      = localhost
  sql_user      = username
  sql_pass      = *******
  sql_db        = db_name
  sql_port      = 3306  # optional, default is 3306

  sql_query     = \
    SELECT id, msgtext, created \
    FROM agi_sms

  sql_attr_string = msgtext
  sql_attr_timestamp    = created

  sql_query_info        = SELECT * FROM agi_sms WHERE id=$id
```

}

```
   index test1
   {
  source            = src1
  path          = C:/Sphinx/data/test1
  docinfo           = extern
  charset_type      = sbcs
  enable_star = 1
  morphology = stem_en
  min_infix_len = 2
  infix_fields = msgtext
  dict = keywords

    }



    indexer
    {
       mem_limit        = 32M
    }


    searchd
    {
  listen            = 9312
  listen            = 9306:mysql41
  log           = C:/Sphinx/log/searchd.log
  query_log     = C:/Sphinx/log/query.log
  read_timeout      = 5
  max_children      = 30
  pid_file      = C:/Sphinx/log/searchd.pid
  max_matches       = 1000
  seamless_rotate       = 1
  preopen_indexes       = 1
  unlink_old        = 1
  workers           = threads # for RT to work
  binlog_path       = C:/Sphinx/data
    }
```

This is my php file:

```
$cl = new SphinxClient ();
$q = $_POST['search'];
$sql = "";
$mode = SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2;
$host = "localhost";
$port = 9312;
$index = "*";
$groupby = "";
$filter = "created";
$filtervals = array();
$distinct = "";
$sortby = "";

$sortexpr = "";
$limit = 20;
$ranker = SPH_RANK_PROXIMITY_BM25;
$select = "";

////////////
// do query
////////////

  $cl = new SphinxClient();
  $cl->SetServer( "localhost", 9312 );
  $cl->SetMatchMode( SPH_MATCH_ANY );
  $cl->SetFilter( 'created', array( 3 ) );

$res = $cl->Query ( $q, $index );
////////////////
// print me out
////////////////

if ( $res===false )
{
  print "Query failed: " . $cl->GetLastError() . ".\n";

} else
{
  if ( $cl->GetLastWarning() )
    print "WARNING: " . $cl->GetLastWarning() . "\n\n";

  print "<li>Query '$q' retrieved $res[total] of $res[total_found] matches in $res[time] sec.\n</li>";
  print "<li>Query stats:\n";
  if ( is_array($res["words"]) )
    foreach ( $res["words"] as $word => $info )
      print "    '$word' found $info[hits] times in $info[docs] documents\n</li>";
  print "\n";


}
```

The results:

```
Query 'good' retrieved 0 of 0 matches in 0.007 sec.
Query stats: 'good' found 7534 times in 7534 documents
```

But if I try to search 'goo', it searched nothing.

```
Query 'goo' retrieved 0 of 0 matches in 0.000 sec.
Query stats: 'goo' found 0 times in 0 documents
```

I want to get the results with everything has a word/letter of '**goo**'.

like this :

```
Array(1 element) {
    0 Object {
        id = 1,
        message = Good Morning
    }
    2 Object {
        id = 2,
        message = Good Day!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> $cl->SetFilter( 'created', array( 3 ) );
>   are you sure you have records with created=3?
>   Also for wildcard searching you should do 'goo*' ( mark the * ) or set expand_keywords = 1.

Comment: I had a similar problem and the `expand_keywords=1` was what I was missing.  That allowed users to not have to type a * for wildcard searches.  Thank you!